# Use exec/fork to run external process

Tags: c++, exec, fork

I am using C++ and trying to run a shell command in an external process. Here is the code I have so far:

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){ 
    execv(args[0],args);
} else {
    wait();
}
```

My first problem is that I need to get the output from the shell command passed to exec and I do not know how to get that. After running the code above the main program also duplicates itself and I am not sure why.

Comment: You should also handle the case when `pid == -1`. Even if to just print an error message and exit.

Comment: You should have an `exit(1);` and probably a printed message after the `execv()`.  Your 'duplicates itself' probably occurs because `argv[0]` is `"ls"` rather than `"/bin/ls"` and `execv()` does not do a search using PATH.  Therefore, the `execv()` fails, and the child continues with more or less whatever the parent would have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args[0]` is presumably the name of the running program, so it will fork and then exec itself.

In order to collect output, you will need to arrange to explicitly pass it.  The Unix `pipe()` call is frequently used for this.

Comment: args[0] is not the name of the running program. In my example program it is 'ls'